# What project type do I choose in eclipse for a spring mvc web app?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

What project type in eclipse do I choose when I want a spring mvc web application? (i'm not using maven).

I want a layout where I can choose the folder names.

i want them to be similiar in layout to how spring's sample applications are setup (basic mvc, petclinic etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd choose a standard web project and put the Spring JARS in the WEB-INF/lib.  The Spring context XML would be loaded by the ContextLoaderListener, and the path would be declared in the web.xml.

Comment: In the new project wizard, I see 'web/static web project' and 'web/dynamic web project' is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure - I don't use Eclipse.  (I find IntelliJ to be far superior.)  I'd look in the help to see what the difference is.  My guess would be "web/dynamic web project".

Answer (score 1):

I usually just go with Java Project, and build the rest of the structure myself.  If I was building apps regularly, I'd skip past this, but building new apps infrequently, it strongly helps me re-familiarize with where everything is in that schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring IDE http://www.springsource.org/springide/release-20 to get help to create config files.

Comment: Or, better yet, the SpringSource ToolSuite